# How to Enable AMD-V virtualization on Lenovo G585

Tags: lenovo, virtualization, bios, genymotion

According to genymotion I don't have virtualization enabled (VM installed through apt-get and genymotion from the page) cannot virtualize with VM either...

> your CPU is incompatible with virtualization technologies

My CPU should support "virtualization:AMD-V" as the `lscpu` command says.

But when I go into my BIOS menu to enable virtualization I can't find where to enable it. There is nowhere anything about CPU or Virtualization or Advanced options which I've seen mentioned elsewhere.

[image: configuration]

[image: security]

Comment: whatis the output of `grep svm -c /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: From your screen shot (configuration)  you had SVM disabled. Enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable it in your BIOS.

Unfortunately, some vendors cripple / disable options in your BIOS. Very frustrating.

First thing you should try is to update your BIOS. If that does not work you will have to write your own. I had to do this for my laptop, frustrating.

See https://www.bios-mods.com/

Be careful as you can brick your box doing this.